# Issue with location using PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, the dialog of settings.api not enable gps

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

i'm using Location Settings from play services and in pre-lollipop works well but in marshmallow, gps isn't enabled, neither says or display in dialog, about to using gps only wifi and cell network , and location mode change only to Battery saving.

i´m sorry for my english i´m from mexico.
this is my code:

```
public void ActivarWifiGps(boolean gpsrequerido){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "se llamo al popup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("sms", "se llamo al popup");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this).
                addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

     mGoogleApiClient.connect();

       mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
      mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        if(gpsrequerido) {
            //EVEN ENTER HERE...
            Log.i("sms", "se usara gps");
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }else{
            Log.i("sms", "se usara wifi");
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        }
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);

        builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);


       // builder.setNeedBle(true);
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {


                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        //...}





                            Log.i("sms", "todo bien");
                            obj.comenzar();



                        Log.i("sms", "estan disponibles");
                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HOLA 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.

                        Log.i("sms", "Motrando popup");
                        //  if( !state.isNetworkLocationPresent()|| !state.isLocationUsable()){

                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HOLA 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        // }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HOLA 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        //...
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

this is dialog:
[image]

Comment: What `permissions` are you using in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: thank you for answer me ,but  resolved already ,i think that the  problem was the emutator of sdk ,i tested in genymotion and  works well..